# What is the correct way to obtain the count of calendars per domain?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-calendar-api

I am trying to obtain the number of calendar resources per domain using the [Calendar Resources API](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/calendar-resource/) , and the code is returning what's deemed as bad results. Specifically, the code insists that all domains have the same calendar count.
I have two functions to do that, both returning the same (bad) results:

```
def getCalendarCountFor(domain, userMail, password):
    client = CalendarResourceClient(domain=domain)
    client.ClientLogin(userMail, password, "test_app")
    calendar_resources = client.GetResourceFeed()
    return len(calendar_resources.entry)
```

The second version:

```
def GoogleQueryCalendars(dom, admin_id, admin_pwd):
    today = datetime.datetime.now().strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%S")
    calendarClient = CalendarResourceClient(domain=dom)
    calendarClient.ClientLogin(email=admin_id, password=admin_pwd, source='TheSource')
    resourceCount = 0
        # loop through all the calendar feeds
    try:
        moreCalendars =calendarClient.GetResourceFeed()
    except:
        print "Exception"
    calendars = {}
    while moreCalendars.entry is not None:
        for i, cal in enumerate(moreCalendars.entry):
            str = cal.GetResourceCommonName()
            pseudoDomain = re.sub("[^A-Z\d]", "", re.search("^[^-\s]*", str).group(0)).lower()
            if pseudoDomain in calendars:
                calendars[pseudoDomain] +=1
            else:
                calendars[pseudoDomain] =1
            resourceCount +=1
        try:
            moreCalendars = calendarClient.GetNext(moreCalendars)
        except:
            break
    return resourceCount
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method for counting calendar resources.

```
def count_resources(domain, email, password):
    client = CalendarResourceClient(domain=domain)
    client.ClientLogin(email=email, 
                       password=password, 
                       source='TheSource')

    count = 0
    uri = client.MakeResourceFeedUri()
    while uri:
        feed = client.GetResourceFeed(uri)
        count += len(feed.entry)

        next_link = feed.GetNextLink()
        uri = next_link.href if next_link else None

    return count
```

Comment: it's returning the same results for me. +1 because at least now we have 3 ways to obtain that count.